# Jquery plugin with split image hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I need jquery plugin to implement this functionality. I have two images with clean and dirty floor. On hover floor should be "cleaning".  [image]

Comment: please provide addition info  like code of what you have done so far. html css js anything.

Comment: To get you started with google for basic functionality what you are looking for is overlay image with animation to move the overlapping image horizontally. Or you could search for plugin with similar thing.

Comment: This could help: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Before-After-Image-Comparison-Plugin-Image-Reveal/dist/demo/

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I recommend to use two images for doing that ..! On hover, replace them which each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen twoface.js used on a popular website (or maybe different code with the same name):

Git: https://gist.github.com/hongymagic/2403518

You can search for twoface.js for a demo of it in action on jsfiddle.

It probably would be just as easy to overlay two images and then use your own code to create a slider to control the width of the top image.